# How to add a check constraint in django model that a field value startwith letter 'c' or 'e' or 'a'

Tags: django, django-models, check-constraints

How to add a check constraint in django model that a field value startwith letter 'c' or 'e' or 'a'
like the bellow SQL check constraint

```
CREATE TABLE Account (
    account_no varchar(12),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    City varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Person CHECK (SUBSTR(account_no,1,1) = 'c' OR SUBSTR(account_no,1,1) = 'e' OR SUBSTR(account_no,1,1) = 'a' )
);
```

i try with meta class of model. but i don't know how to specify the or case

```
  class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check = Q(account_no___startswith=F('')), 
                name = 'check_start_wtih',
            ),
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check = Q(account_no___startswith='c') | Q(account_no___startswith='e') | Q(account_no___startswith='a'), 
                name = 'check_start_wtih_cea',
            ),
        ]
```

Comment: an error shows up core.User: (models.E012) 'constraints' refers to the nonexistent field 'a'.

Comment: ah it probably should be just `Q(account_no___startswith='c') | Q(account_no___startswith='e') | Q(account_no___startswith='a')` then

Comment: Thankyou Eugene for the support. sorry for the late response.